# Equivalence relation on the disjoint union of all sections of a presheaf - verify transitivity

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and associate to each open subset $U \subset X$ a set $S(U)$ in such a way that whenever $V \subset U$ is another open subset the so called restriction maps $\rho_V^U \colon S(U) \to S(V)$ satisfy the condition $$\rho_W^V \circ \rho_V^U = \rho_V^U \qquad \rho_U^U = \text{id}_U$$ for all open $W \subset V \subset U$. The collection $S = \{S(U), \rho_V^U\}$ is then called a presheaf on $X$. Now given a presheaf $S = \{S(U), \rho_V^U\}$ we may consider the disjoint union $$\mathcal{U}_x = \bigsqcup\limits_{U \ni x} S(U)$$ where the union is taken over all open subsets $U$ which contain $x \in X$. For $f \in S(U)$ and $g \in S(V)$ define the relation $$f \sim g \iff \exists x \in W \subset U \cap V \colon \rho_W^U(f) = \rho_W^V(g)$$
Quite evidently this relation is reflexive and symmetric. However, why does it satisfy transitivity? If $h \in S(N)$ such that $f \sim g$ and $g \sim h$, then by assumption there are open neighborhoods $W_1, W_2 \subset X$ of $x$ such that $\rho_{W_1}^U(f) = \rho_{W_1}^V(g)$ and $\rho_{W_2}^V(g) = \rho_{W_2}^N(h)$. Setting $W = W_1 \cap W_2$, I guess the idea would be $$\rho_W^U(f) = \rho_W^{W_1} \circ \rho_{W_1}^U(f) = \rho_W^{W_1}(\rho_{W_2}^V(g)) \underset{\text{Is this valid?}}{=} \rho_W^{W_2} \circ \rho_{W_2}^{V}(g) = \rho_W^{W_2} \circ \rho_{W_2}^{N}(h) = \rho_W^N(h)$$ I don't quite see how one could justify the transition from $W_1$ to $W_2$ in the upper index of $\rho$. I either probably overlook something completely trivial, or I am just mistaken (or both), so I guess the question is:

> How to properly show transitivity of this relation?

Comment: Let me just point out that you already have a mistake right after the second equality: you write $\rho^{W_1}_W(\rho^V_{W_2}(g))$ when the subscripted $W$s should have matching subscripts. (You may also find it helpful to talk this one out - if two functions are the same once you restrict to a neighborhood, restricting any further will keep them the same.)

Comment: @KReiser Yes I messed up the indices there, and I guess that's what ultimately got me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a single step:
$$\begin{align}\rho^U_W(f)&=\rho^{W_1}_W(\rho^U_{W_1}(f))&\text{composition of restrictions}\\
&=\rho^{W_1}_W(\rho^V_{W_1}(g))&\text{assumption $f\sim g$}\\
&\color{red}{=\rho^{V}_W(g)}&\text{composition of restrictions}\\
&=\rho^{W_2}_W(\rho^V_{W_2}(g))&\text{composition of restrictions}\\
&=\rho^{W_2}_W(\rho^N_{W_2}(h))&\text{assumption $g\sim h$}\\
&=\rho^N_{W}(h)&\text{composition of restrictions}\\
\end{align}$$

In fact, one clearly has that sections that are equal after restriction are still equal after stronger restriction.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I indeed overlooked something completely trivial there!